# How to evaluate/store JS/HTML code into a PHP variable instead of displaying it?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, buffer

I have a PHP file *paypal.php*.

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=<?php echo get_paypal('client-id'); ?>&vault=true&intent=subscription" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>
<script>
paypal.Buttons({
    // ...
}).render('#paypal-button-container-<?php echo get_paypal('plan-id'); ?>');
```

I want to evaluate *paypal.php* in another php file and store the evaluation result in a variable and then output it to the user at later time.

Using this approach

```
$content = eval('?>' . file_get_contents('paypal.php') . '<?php');
```

the `script` tag is being echo-ed and the javascript is executed in the browser. But I do not want it to be echo-ed. I just want to keep the result for further processing.

How can I **avoid echo-ing the evaluation result** and **just store the result in a variable**?

Comment: It's not clear what you actually mean. If you don't output the JS code to the browser, it cannot be executed. Are you saying you just want to get the raw contents of `paypal.php` as a string in PHP?

Comment: I don't understand what you're getting at. You have a PHP file that contains only JavaScript. PHP won't run that, so when you execute `file_get_contents()` it will just send the raw JavaScript. PHP is executed on the server, while JavaScript is executed in the browser. You can't mix the two.

Comment: Probably related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13840429/14853083

Comment: I do not want to get the raw content. This can be done by just using file_get_contents. I want to get the code after being evaluated by the php interpreter.

Comment: eval() doesn't return a value (unless the script it's executing contains a `return`) - this is clear in the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php). So it's just executing the code and it's outputting as usual. It's not storing it in $content. That's the reason your code isn't doing what you wanted. Output buffering, as per [the answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76895148/5947043) is a reasonable solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To store some content in a PHP variable before it's displayed, you can use PHP buffering functions [`ob_start()`](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.ob-start.php) and [`ob_get_clean()`](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.ob-get-clean.php) as follows:

```php
<?php 
    ob_start(); // Start buffering 
?>
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=<?php echo get_paypal('client-id'); ?>&vault=true&intent=subscription" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>
<script>
paypal.Buttons({
    // ...
}).render('#paypal-button-container-<?php echo get_paypal('plan-id'); ?>');
<?php 
// We can now store the buffered content in a variable
$buffered_content = ob_get_clean(); 
?>
```